# Unable to insert custom lookup fields into a custom object through apex code

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Here is my entire code, I am working in Visual studio code 
I have created a custom object 'Price', having two custom look up fields (Project, Unit) and some other fields,. I am trying to insert values into this custom object, but the look up field values(Project, Unit) are not getting inserted, all other fields got inserted.

Html template

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
          <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">

            <lightning-input label="Date" name="datefld" type="date" value={fDate} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Enquirer" name="enquiry" type="textarea" value={enq} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Project__c" required onchange={projectChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Unit__c"  onchange={unitChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    
    
   <lightning-input label="Unit Rate" name="rate" type="Double" value={rNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Additional cost" name="cost" type="Double" value={cNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Discount" name="dis" type="Double" value={dNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Agreement cost" name="agree" type="Double" value={aNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Remarks" name = "remark" type="textarea" value={resultsum} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input> 
    
     <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    
    
           </p>
           </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement ,api, wire, track} from 'lwc';

import newPrice from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.newPrice';
export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
    datefld;
    enquiry;
    projSelected;
    unitSelected;
    rate;
    cost;
    dis;
    agree;
    remark;
 
    handledChange(event){

        if(event.target.name==='datefld'){

            console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value);

            this.datefld = event.target.value;

        }
        else if(event.target.name==='enquiry'){

            console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)

            this.enquiry = event.target.value;    
       }

        else if(event.target.name==='rate'){

            console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)

            this.rate = event.target.value;    
       }
       else if(event.target.name==='cost'){

        console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)

        this.cost = event.target.value;    

    }
    else if(event.target.name==='dis'){

        console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)

        this.dis = event.target.value;    
        
   
    }
    else if(event.target.name==='agree'){

        console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)

        this.agree = event.target.value;    

    }
    else if(event.target.name==='remark'){

        console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)

        this.remark = event.target.value;    

    }
    }
    projectChange(event) {
        projSelected = event.detail;
    }
    unitChange(event) {
        unitSelected = event.detail;
    }
   handleClick(event) {
        newPrice({ entryDate: this.datefld, enqName : this.enquiry, proj:projSelected, unit:unitSelected,
             unitRate:this.rate, addtnlCost:this.cost, discount:this.dis, agreeCost:this.agree,rem:this.remark })

        .then(result => {

            this.result = result;
           if(this.result == 'true') {
               alert("SUCCESS");
           }
        })
        .catch(error => {
             this.error = error;
             alert("FAILURE" + error);
              //this.error = error;
        });
    }
}
```

PriceFetch.cls (Apex controler class)

```
public with sharing class PriceFetch {
  
 
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean newPrice(Date entryDate, String enqName, Id proj, Id unit,Double unitRate,Double addtnlCost, Double discount,Double agreeCost, String rem ){
     
       Price__c price = new Price__c();
       price.Date__c = entryDate;
       price.Name = enqName;
       price.Project__c = proj;
       price.Unit__c = unit;
       price.Unit_Rate__c = unitRate;
       price.Additional_cost__c = addtnlCost;
       price.Discount__c = discount;
       price.Agreement_cost__c = agreeCost;
       price.Remarks__c = rem;
       try {
        insert price;
        return true;
           
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AuraHandledException('exceptionText' + e.getMessage());
         
       }
      
    }
}
```

​​​​​​​Is there any mistake in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You are missing `this` keyword while passing some attributes to the imperative function

```js
handleClick(event) {
    newPrice({
        entryDate: this.datefld,
        enqName: this.enquiry,
        proj: this.projSelected, // this was missing on this line
        unit: this.unitSelected,// this was missing on this line
        unitRate: this.rate,
        addtnlCost: this.cost,
        discount: this.dis,
        agreeCost: this.agree,
        rem: this.remark
    })
        .then(result => {
            this.result = result;
            if (this.result == "true") {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            alert("FAILURE" + error);
            //this.error = error;
        });
}
```

2. The value returned by `lightning-input-field` component for a field of type lookup, is an array so you need to change the method.

   projectChange(event) {
   this.projSelected = event.detail.value[0];
   }

Again, you were missing `this` in the below function, and to get the value you need to access the value property of an event or the target like `event.detail.value` or `event.target.value`.

```
unitChange(event) {
    this.unitSelected = event.detail.value;
}
```

**Note:- that every time you access the class property in the js code you need to access that with this keyword, otherwise, you will run into an error.**